# How to construct SQL query to get the output as below

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-query-store

the below image is how the table related and the expected output result.

[image]

I used MySQL version 6.3.3. and the below is currently can be achieved.

[image]

and below is the SQL query code

```
select table2.Status as StatusName, count(table1.Status) as NoOfStatus from testingdb.table1, testingdb.table2 where table1.Status=table2.Status group by table1.Status;
```

Anyone can help me to improvise the SQL query code above to get the expected output is very appreciated and thank you very much...

Comment: I used MySQL version 6.3.3 - can't have there is no such version please publish result of select version().

Comment: Why tag query-store which is relevant to an unrelated product? 
As explained in the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), do not post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of code or data, text should be *text*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use ROLLUP functionality

```
CREATE TABLE table_a (
  item varchar(20),
  item_code varchar(20),
  item_status varchar(1)
);

CREATE TABLE table_b (
  item_status varchar(1),
  item_status_name varchar(200)
);

INSERT INTO table_a VALUES ('101', 'SEQ', 'A'),
('202', 'FEQ', 'A'),
('303', 'AEQ', 'C'),
('404', 'BEQ', 'B'),
('505', 'CEQ', 'B'),
('606A', 'BEQ', 'B'),
('505B', 'CEQ', 'B'),
('606', 'GEQ', 'D'),
('707', 'HEQ', 'E');


INSERT INTO table_b VALUES ('A', 'Completed'),('B', 'Half-Completed'),('C', 'Started'),('D', 'Negotiated'),('E', 'OnProposal');
```

And here is the super simple query:

```
SELECT b.item_status_name as status_name
, count(item) as nbr_of_progress
FROM table_a a 
LEFT JOIN table_b b 
ON b.item_status = a.item_status
GROUP BY b.item_status_name WITH ROLLUP
```

see the [live demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eYqnMkUV2RTP78Fvx5pooi/0)

read more about [group by and rollup](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html#:%7E:text=The%20GROUP%20BY%20clause%20permits,analysis%20with%20a%20single%20query.)